# Docker is creating folder instead of file

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile

I am usin Docker desktop on my macOS to deploy some project.

I am getting error that my commands are creating folder instead of file. We tried the exact same project, files and commands on my friends computer that as me running MacOS and everything was running without a problem. File is created and not folder.

If I bult Image it is created without a problem. Problem comes with run command.

Our file-sharing settings are the same. And I have owner permissions for the project.

> 2024-01-16 12:26:34 IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/app/service-account.json'

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t data_inventory .`
```

```
`docker run -d -v /Users/dada/Source/eden/keys/data-inventory/container-testing-381309-2a388349e943.json:/app/service-account.json -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/service-account.json data_inventory
```

Docker build looks like this and works for my friend with commands above just fine.

```
# Use an official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LOGGING_LEVEL "INFO"
ENV PROJECT_ID "container-test"
ENV DATASET_ID "nventory"
ENV TABLE_ID "nv_data"
ENV EDEN_PUBLIC_PROJECT "data-public"
ENV EDEN_PRIVATE_PROJECT "data-private"

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Create a virtual environment in the container
# This environment is isolated from the global Python environment
RUN python -m venv venv

# Activate the virtual environment
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Install system dependencies (if any, remove if not needed)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy requirements file and install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy your application code into the container
COPY ./ /app

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD ["python", "app/main.py"]
```

I have tried to check my macOS path, that is fine. I have checked if Docker is installed rigt, also tried to build image in different ways... [image]

We test run it on the exact same code on my friends comoputer that runs macOS and it works for him.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind mount something on the host that doesn't exist, it's always created as a directory. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior):

> If you use `-v` or `--volume` to bind-mount a file or directory that
> does not yet exist on the Docker host, `-v` creates the endpoint for
> you. It is always created as a directory.

If it works on your friend's computer, the file must exist before the `docker run` command is run.